# how to remove node modules from github (release Branch)

Tags: angular, git, github, visual-studio-code, node-modules

Currently i was working under release branch where I am facing a issue that is when i try to commit my code to the Git.

I was able to see all node Modules is available in my github desktop Please find a reference for the same. Which i don't want to commit this files.

This is my .gitignore file

[image]

[image]

Folder structure for the refrence

[image: Folder structure]

Comment: add `/node_modules` to your gitignore file

Comment: it is already there in ui/node_modules

Comment: yeap you need to add `ui/node_modules/**/*` line to .gitignore file...

Comment: you mean to say instead of line 9 right

Comment: why post an image of your `.gitignore` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if those files were already committed in the past, you would need to remove them (from Git, not from your disk) in order for them to be ignored:

```
git rm --cached -r ui/node_modules
```

Second, even before committing, you can check if your .gitingore works with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- ui/node_modules/aFile
```

(replace `aFile` with an actual file)

If it does return nothing, double-check the content of your `.gitignore`.
If that file is directly in the `ui` folder, right above `node_modules`, then the rule needs to be

```
node_modules/
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to ignore `node_modules` folder. To do that just add `ui/node_modules/**/*` line to your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: but appeared node_modules folder seems to be in root of the git repository, doesn't it?

Comment: actually there are two folder here i have backend and front end this nodemodules under front end i am getting the issue

Comment: if you see i have attached my folder screen shot

Comment: after adding ui/node_modules/**/* this also when i check the github desktop I am getting the same

Comment: In that case try steps recommended by @VonC. Is it possible they have been committed in the past? Also, `check-ignore` could be handy...